# How to delete a user in oracle?

Tags: oracle, ddl

my question is about deleting a user in Oracle. I received an error, try Oracle sqlplus and the developer.

**oracle sql developer :**

[connection in the Oracle SQL developer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6R8Wf.png)

```
Drop user HOLA CASCADE;
```

error:
Error starting at line: 13 of the command:
Drop user HELLO CASCADE
Error Report -
ORA-00604: error occurred in recursive level 1 SQL
ORA-00942: the table or view does not exist
00604. 00000 - "error occurred at recursive SQL level% s"
* Cause: An error occurred while processing a recursive SQL statement
(a statement that applies to tables of internal dictionaries).
* Action: if the situation is described in the following error in the stack
it can be corrected, do it; otherwise, contact Oracle support.

**sqlplus:**

```
Enter user-name: sys as sysdba
Enter password:

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL> Drop user "HOLA" CASCADE;
Drop user "HOLA" CASCADE
          *
ERROR at line 1:
the user 'HOLA' does not exist
```

[consult in the oracle to verify the user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNrpf.png)

Comment: What is that user's *real* name? You're showing HOLA nad HELLO, using uppercase, uppercase enclosed into double quotes ... It would help if you posted what's really going on. I, somehow, doubt that Oracle translated HOLA to HELLO.

Comment: The user is "HOLA" was used for a test.

Comment: Hola is Spanish for hello isn't it?. I think a little translation was going on there.  Are you sure the user actually exists still?  Can you query the users system table and show us that you actually have such a user?  `Select * from USER_USERS where username = 'HOLA';` and if you eliminate the cascade; do you get an error indicating it can't delete the user because dependent objects exist?

Comment: select * from all_users where username = 'HOLA';

Answer (score 0):

> *The `ORA-600 type error` is the generic internal error number for Oracle program exceptions. It indicates that a process has encountered
>   a low-level, unexpected condition.*

*There's no problem with your issued command normally. I suspect about a `DDL trigger` which you cannnot reach, most probably located in `system` or `sys` users. Maybe a there's at least one trigger of type `before ddl on database` or `before drop on database`. If it's not a production database, or if not problematic for your DB's routine operations and tasks, then those triggers may be disabled by your `DB Admin`.*